# Alternative way to install Message Queuing (MSMQ)

Tags: windows, windows-10, msmq

I have Windows 10 and "Turn Windows Features on or off" is empty.
So I can't add/install MSMQ using it.
I don't know when "Windows Features" window become this (empty) so I can't use Windows Restore (I don't know what date to choose and I've installed some programs last days so I don't want to use it anyway)

Is there an alternative way to enable MSMQ?

[image]

Comment: See http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-windows-features-on-or-off-blank to get the Tuen Windows Feature on or off working first

Comment: @GaneshR. I already saw it (of course I googled this error) - didn't help

Comment: I think fixing this issue is imperative before you can enable MSMQ

Comment: Check the eventvwr for any errors when you open this dialog

Comment: @GaneshR. Nothing there. Anyway there is a way to enable MSMQ using powershell - http://serverfault.com/questions/554462/is-it-possible-to-enable-msmq-from-powershell-on-windows-8

Comment: @GaneshR. but yeah you right. I won't be able to install MSMQ even using powershell - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d046ad6c-0520-4478-b4fe-f1f87543795e/why-dism-online-getfeatures-claims-that-this-is-not-a-valid-package-?forum=w8itprogeneral There is also a problem with DISM restore, but I'm going to try DISM with source iso from Tech Bench - http://superuser.com/a/980066 (people say it works with it)

Comment: omg dism restorehealth with iso from tech bench was successful 100% but it still didn't solve the problem with empty features window so I don't even know what is f wrong with that

Comment: I would suggest do a clean install of Windows if nothing is working

Comment: @GaneshR. haha, thanks, but no) it's 2016, check my answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36773687/4548520 I just updated all system files. so clean install is insane move for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.. "Windows Features & Installed updates" empty/blank issue should be fixed anyway. Pretty easy **Solution** (works 100%):

1. download iso of your Win OS, for e.g. Windows 10 -
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench - free
   to download any Win 10 from official MS servers..
2. just open this iso, run Setup.exe (windows explorer can easily open iso files itself, so you don't need flash device or dvd) and just update your OS:

[image]

[image]

your files, installed programs/apps will **not** be removed :) it just reinstalls system files

**source**: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/957310 - check
    "Способ 4. Выполнить обновление на месте" - yeah it's in Russian and I don't know why English version doesn't have it...
    https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/kb/957310

p.s.
`sfc /scannow` or `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`- none of this helped me, but you could try it first and see if it helps

you can also try MS "System Update Readiness" tool https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/kb/947821 (I didn't use it but mb it also can fix it)

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Windows **PowerShell** as Administrator.
2. To get a list of available features, Type **Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -online | ft**
3. **Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName XXXXXX**
     Replace XXXXXX with the feature you wish to enable.